# Can the dual of a problem has no solution if the primal has a solution?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, operations-research

I'm having a problem with linear programming, the primal function is given by:

$$\text{minimize }z = 5x_1 - 6x_2 - 7x_3$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_1 + 5x_2 - 3x_3 &\ge 15 \\
5x_1 -6x_2 +10x_3 &\le 20 \\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &\le 5 \\
x_i &\ge 0\hspace{1cm}(i=1,2,3) 
\end{align}

which has an optimal solution, although when I find the dual and solve it it has no solution at all:

$$\text{maximize }z = 15x_1 -20x_2 - 5x_3 + 5x_4$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_1 - 5x_2 - x_3 + x_4 &\le 5 \\
5x_1 + 6x_2 - x_3 + x_4 &\le -6 \\
-3x_1 - 10x_2 - x_3 + x_4 &\le -7 \\
x_i&\ge 0\hspace{1cm}(i=1,2,3,4)
\end{align}

How is this even possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I transcribed your images into MathJax so that readers won't have to click on a link to see your equations. Please check that I didn't make any transcription errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is not possible. Your dual problem is wrong, which should explain why you do not find a solution. The dual should be
$$
\max\quad 15x_1+20x_2+5x_3
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_1+5x_2+x_3 &\le 5\\
5x_1-6x_2+x_3 &\le -6\\
-3x_1+10x_2+x_3 &\le -7\\
x_1 &\ge 0\\
x_2,x_3 &\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}